# Describing a worsening crisis

Tags: phrases

How can I describe that the financial crisis got worse in two ways:

1. it involved more people
2. it increased in intensity

Is there a particular phrase I can use that captures both aspects?

Comment: There's no sugar-coating it: you can't make a financial crisis sound nice without the use of *Schadenfreude*.

Comment: Sorry by "sounds nice" I mean... make sense in English!

Comment: I know. I was just kidding you.

Comment: OK ;-) Nice one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest:

> The financial crisis broadened and deepened.

That is, it affected more people and increased in effect.

Comment: dangit, you beat me by 47 seconds.

Comment: @Hellion: Asleep at the wheel again, I take it?

Comment: I suppose you could say i was asleep at the wheel or something.